Giant War-Marbles of Doom: What's the Biggest possible Spherical Vehicle we could Build?
I had a concept for Giant War-Marbles of Doom rolling across a giant Birch Planet with Earth-like gravity. The floor of this world would be incredibly thick steel, intended as armour against relativistic strikes. The marble would be a war-vehicle, a mostly-solid ball with corridors, command centres, and other such rooms inside it.
I am curious how big the war marble could reasonably be with known materials; Steel, Carbon Nanotubes, Graphene, or any others. How big would physics allow us to build it and have it roll across the land, presuming no budget or engineering limitations?

I'm up-voting for "Giant War-Marbles of Doom." Hallelujah.

If you can say what power-to-weight ratio these things engines might have, we could speculate as to the maximum practical size and weight of the things that would allow them to move.

@MontyWild That's tricky to establish. I was considering them pumping mercury into a chamber on the upper front side of the sphere, so it naturally rolls forward. You might even use a miniature blackhole. I'm not sure what to look up to find details on how to internally get a ball rolling, though Mark Rober did make a guided bowling ball akin to this. But I'm not sure what thrust it'd generate using future tech. Would you have any ideas?

Mercury is less dense than tungsten, and you'd need a material with a higher compression strength than steel.  I doubt that you'd get very much power out of such an arrangement.

I added link to Birch Planet. BTW, the Megastructures Encyclopedia that I linked to is a good resource for anyone working regularly on this site — well written and illustrated.

two big problem we know becasue people actually tried to build sphrical tanks, 1. how do you see out of it? the whole thing needs ot be clear to see where you are going, and it also can't get dirty. 2. a sphere has a very small contact point so it has very little traction.

Archduchess: I expect your future questions will be about bumpers and flippers for defending against war marbles. I look forward to reading this book!

@MontyWild Ah, hadn't originally thought of tungsten.  Here's the video from Mark, which may be a possible form of locomotion via gravity (a bit like walking): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM5NHC97JBw For mass, you could use a mini blackhole, or liquid osmium or such. You could also use a pendulum like Mark did. I see in your answer you made a good point that it may have to roll uphill, making gravity propulsion difficult. I would consider using nuclear bombs as propulsion, as they'd be the least destructive part of this vehicle.

Once it gets rolling, it’ll have lots of inertia on a mostly flat world, so the big challenge is steering not motoring.

@John This is true. Though at the massive scale we're talking about it's more like Iserlohn Fortress except on the ground. I was considering making it a giant trapezoid, with kilometers of treads, alternatively, but giant marbles is a really neat idea. For visuals, they'd likely rely on aircraft and ground scouting forces, mainly. Traction wouldn't be great, but you don't move this on anything less than the strategic level already, so a few hundred meters off-target probably doesn't matter. At the sizes Monty suggested, for one with existing materials, you need a heck of a weapon to hurt it.

@SRM Hey SRM, thanks, glad you find it interesting! And good idea to link to a source on Birch Planets. I wonder what it means about the physics not working out with them, though? Steering it would be a challenge certainly. Mark Rober did show off the ability to steer a bowling ball pretty well with a gyroscopic pendulum, though, so I presume it's possible. These marbles were originally built by a pretty insane intergalactic empire, but I could see some major characters using the smaller ones to assault planets, archeotech style. On the birch planet, these mostly suppressed uprisings/coups.

You sent me down a bit of a rabbit hole: I think the physics don’t work because the shell requires active support to remain stable around a black hole and there’s not an energy source big enough to provide that support. A Dyson sphere around a star is far more stable AND draws power from the star sufficient for ops if needed. The physics seem vastly different for Birch planet. If you want a better answer, ask this as a formal question on WB! :-) (So move your war marbles to a Dyson sphere!)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Since these are war machines it's basically certain that they aren't going to build anywhere near the engineering limits.  When war machines are hit they cease to remain static forces.  Consider what happens when a large nuke goes off overhead.  A marble near the max could be shoved through the floor by a boom that wouldn't actually do much damage.

@LorenPechtel This is a good point, thank you. I was curious about the physical limit so it could give me an idea of the sort of sizes they may have. If you'd like to discuss more of the practicalities, you're welcome to join us in the chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154713/discussion-between-archduchessferdinand-and-srm

Since these war marbles of doom could be made from any material, the ultimate limiting factor in the size of these spheres is going to be ground pressure.  The OP has said that the birch-world floors are going to be made from steel, and we can presume that this will be the highest compressive-strength steel available, maraging steel.  Maraging steel has a compressive strength of 2.4 GPa.
A war marble could be made from graphene, the material with supposedly the highest compressive strength, but its failure mode would be fracturing, so any particularly high point loading would result in the marble cracking.  Once cracked, the crack would tend to propagate.  For a war machine, this is undesirable.
The materials with the next highest compressive strength are tungsten alloys, with a compressive yield strength of up to 8.4 GPa.  As this would probably be subject to ductile failure rather than brittle failure in a spherical object, we can presume that the outer layer of the war marble is made from this or something similar.
The ultimate limit of the useful mass of a sphere in this situation is the mass at which the pressure exerted by the sphere is such that it causes the compression failure of the underlying maraging steel floor of the birch world across the war marble's entire width.  This would result in the war marble simply sinking through the steel like a large steel ball bearing placed on top of gelatine might on a human scale.
The pressure exerted by a sphere upon the ground is described in Pressure of a sphere against the ground and Contact Mechanics.  Contact area is:
$$a = \sqrt[3]{\frac34 FR\left(\frac{1-\nu_1^2}{E_1}+\frac{1-\nu_2^2}{E_2}{}\right)}$$
where:

$v_1$ is the Poisson Ratio of the tungsten sphere (0.270 average)
$E_1$ is the Modulus of Elasticity of the tungsten sphere (340 GPa average)
$v_2$ is the Poisson Ratio of the maraging steel floor (0.3 average)
$E_2$ is the Modulus of Elasticity of the maraging steel floor (188 GPa average)
$R$ is the radius of the sphere
$F$ is the force exerted by the sphere (i.e. its weight in Newtons, which at 1g would be 9.8 times its mass in kg)

$F$ can be calculated by:
$$F = \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3Dg$$
where:

$D$ is the density of the tungsten sphere (assuming 75% of Tungsten's density of 15,400 $kg/m^3$: 11,550$kg/m^3$)
$g$ is gravity ($9.8 m/s^2$)

Maximum Pressure is
$$P_0 = \frac{3F}{2\pi a^2}$$
while minimum pressure is:
$$P_1 = \frac{F}{a}$$
Plugging the formulas and figures into Excel, at a radius of about 0.0655 metres, the weight of the 75% filled tungsten sphere exerts a minimum pressure ($P_1$) in excess of the compressive strength of the maraging steel floor.  That's the point at which the formulas above (and the floor) begin to break down, since they assume no yield point.
So, since pressure is force per unit area, we can calculate the point at which the pressure across the entire area of a circle with a radius identical to that of the sphere exceeds the compressive strength of the floor.
Plugging the numbers into Excel again, at a radius of about 15,903 metres, the minimum pressure ($P_1$) exerted by the sphere across its entire bottom area exceeds the compressive strength of the maraging steel floor, meaning that at that size or larger, the sphere will descend into the steel like a big ball bearing into jelly.
Of course, if the OP wants bigger rather than heavier, the war marble could be made of maraging steel, and it would break down entirely at a radius of 30,613 metres, having the same properties as the steel floor.
While 15,903m is the maximum radius of a sphere that the specified floor can support, we still have the problem of making the sphere move.  That would require a rather smaller sphere so that it would be able to 'climb out' of the trench it leaves in the steel floor, with a reasonable amount of engine power.  Without knowing what motive force is available, I'd just be speculating at this point.

@antares, The OP specified a Birch world, which is a (number of) steel shell(s) around a black hole, this one at 1g.  Even assuming a really thick steel shell, a 15,903+m radius sphere will sink into it without stopping, the bigger the faster... especially as the gravity will only increase as you go down.

Oh whoopsie... didn't realize that! I thought they are birch trees! :D Thanks for enlightening me :)

Great write up. My eyes tricked me because of where line breaks were on my device… I read “a large steel ball bearing placed on top of gelatine might on a human” as “placed on top of a human”. :-)

This was a really great answer, thank you. Wow, 15km max, and that's with known materials and a miraging steel floor. If you presumed unknown materials, like Superdense Steel from the Traveller RPG, you could go even crazier. I wonder if I should post a new question related to the physics of scaling this up to an Earth-mass marble? That would have neat effects, like the odd was gravity would work. You could almost walk upside down inside the marble, except the gravity of the Birch planet would counteract it, making you almost float in the bottom of the marble, I suppose. Thanks again!

There is no physical limiting factor (if disregarding rolling), only practical ones.
Disclaimer: Didn't realize the concept of a Birch-Planet. So the following is more like with our earth in mind and how big the marble of doom could feasibly be.
We are able to build structures of ~830m which get thinner at the top (Burj Khalifa).
A spherical form is much more stable. You can probably make it even floating and moving in (or even under) water to be the ultimate amphibious vessel. Like those human floating balls, but in "good".
In theory you can build a 100km sphere if you like, reaching up to the limit of the atmosphere, given enough time, money, resources, work force, etc.
For being useful as the intended combat vessel, a size of 10m or 100m-500m in diameter might be more reasonable to build in time and be navigable in a larger group of marbles.
This would still limit your movement across mountains or steep canyons, though. Having a marble with 10km in diameter (higher than the Mt. Everest with ~8.8km, broader than the Grand Canyon with ~6km) might be a costly thing to pull off and if it gets destroyed (hard to miss anyway) the loss would be immense.
A larger marble could even be able to deploy smaller ones to explore tighter spaces where the big one cannot go.
Technical Concepts & Inspirations
The marble would be almost hollow tho, at least not mostly solid, from a technical point of view. But according to your in-world tech-level, your milage may vary.
Have a look at the BB-8 robot from StarWars: Enter "ball rotating motor BB8" into your search engine and look for images for inspiration on the interior and driving principles etc.
Note that BB8 is also available as a real life toy which moves like the one in the movies. You can take that as kind of proof-of-concept.
Also have a look at those monowheel bicycles and imagine a spherical shell around them.
The technical term for the marble of doom would probably be something like a "omnidirectional spherical monowheel" (again search for images for inspiration).
A famous example might be those explorer balls from Jurassic World dubbed "Gyrospheres".
Concerning Birch-Sphere/Birch-Planet:
You can consider any planet being of less mass than the Birch-Sphere in total, which has a radius of 1 lightyear. But the problem is, that sphere is not solid. And beyond the sphere there is a black hole lurking, ready to suck-in all matter it can grab hold to.
As Monty-Wild impressively has shown, a ~15km sphere would exert enough gravitational force under 1g (exactly at the surface of the Birch-Sphere) to break through that Birch-Sphere-Metal-Layer "automatically" due to the increasing g-forces closer to the black hole.
Which then comes down to the "moon-planet"-scenario, just magnitudes more severe, because a planet (solid object) would impose a kind of stopping force, while the Birch-Sphere (hollow) would not do that in the same amount and a black hole at the end would never do that, but will disintegrate all matter into gamma rays in the long run probably.
The marble will need to be either far less in size than 15km or needs to constantly counteract gravity by using its propulsion systems - which makes it debatable if this is technically "rolling" or "hovering" over the surface.
Sidenote: A Birch-Sphere is so much not possible (except in fantasy-Sci-Fi of course), that if this would be a real-world scenario the likely outcome would be something like this: Bump into the sphere with 2g of force and you will move the whole sphere a tiny bit closer to the black hole. The sphere only counteracts with 1g, but not because of its mass - It is more like the gravitational potential of the black hole being 1g at this radius and the Birch-Sphere has to be in perfect balance to the black hole (gravity vs. own mass vs. distance), thus floating free of any accelerating forces. Over time after the bump (which could be repeated), the black hole will do the rest, pulling the sphere towards the center in little steps until it breaks. To counteract that a little, the whole sphere has to rotate, which in turn would increase centrifugal forces, either messing up the 1g limit or exceeding stability forces and being ripped apart if rotating too fast.

Hey Antares, thanks for the detailed examples!  My original concept was actually for marbles with the mass of the moon, Earth, or even larger. I figured they'd be mostly solid so that even orbital or relativistic attack may not destroy them, and they could roll over mountain ranges or cities as needed, deploying air and ground forces.   I figured there'd be major issues of material deformation and even problems regarding the Roche limit, but I was unsure about this due to steel (or possibly stronger) properties of the two bodies. Do you have thoughts on if these extremes are possible?

@ArchduchessFerdinand: Oh... not planet sized but planet-weighted... that is a whole different story. Gravity will play a major influence then. I try to give another answer on that.

The Wikipedia article on monowheels also contains a link to https://www.tankarchives.ca/2019/05/in-search-of-perfect-sphere.html

If you want a better real-world example, get a hamster. Fully enclosed ball, small furry motor, motion in any direction.

Scenario: Rolling Moon
Disclaimer: Didn't realize the concept of a Birch-Planet. So the following is more like with "real" planets or moons in mind. Results are transferable, though.
The marble of doom is moon or planet-sized and also solid, meaning having a weight in the class of a moon or planet, which in turn calls for gravitational forces of that scale.
Let's assume for starters the marble is smaller than the planet. Comparable to our moon or like venus or mercury to the size of a (big, rocky) planet like earth.
Gravitational Barycenter:
If two moons or planets circle each other, they do this around the common barycenter of the two. Mostly, this barycenter lies close to the center of the more massive object (only if the mass difference is really huge). If two bodies of the same mass come close to each other, their barycenter will be about halfway between the two.
Due to the gravitational pull, the two bodies will start to spiral around on a descending orbit, gaining speed and momentum and eventually will collide. This collision is on a planetary devastating scale. Much worse as the dinosaur-killer astroid. More like the Earth-Gaia-impact in the early stages of the solar-system which caused our Moon to form.
Movement / Approaching from Space:
The marble needs to be suited for space travel. Having thrusters or any other means of drive/propulsion. If the moon comes closer to the planet, gravitational forces will start to act upon the bodies. Meaning, forces that can put the planet out of its orbit or mess up the rotational axis.
If the approach is really, really careful (meaning slow and controlled, needing thrusters to counteract the gravitational pull), then it might be possible to touchdown on the planet without acting like a planet-destroying-projectile and start rolling over it.
But the changing mass situation in such scales will bring the whole system out of balance all the time. The marble will be gravitationally bound to the planet, but being so large as to be able to influence the planet on its orbit. They will probably start wobbling around uncontrollably making controlled navigation more or less impossible.
Marble sized the same as the planet:
The effects described would be even stronger. And a "rolling" on the surface is impossible. The other body exerts the same forces on the marble and you could not tell who is rolling around whom. Think of the worst case for example: The marble is larger than the "planetoid" to roll on. The planetoid will be pulled towards the marble and sticks there like a gum, due to the gravitational pull.
Size restrictions:
So clearly, in this scenario there are size (mass rather) limitations which govern the "practicability" of the whole thing. I cannot put a number on this really. A significant influence will probably already start below the size and mass of our moon, given that the marble should be in touch at surface-distance = 0 with the planet.
Feasibility:
If engineering, material etc. is not the issue, then it would be plausible to be able to build such an artificial moon. This would need massive, planet-scale acceleration mechanisms etc. Making it costly and an easy target because of the size.
The "good" thing is, that the marble probably will sustain a great deal of damage. Only the most impact-strongest weapons could pose a threat to that marble. Maybe only projectiles in the size and mass level of the marble itself. If relativistic weaponry is a thing, then there might be ways to have such a marble destroyed.
Maybe it is even a good idea to take some moon and equip it with armor plates, hangars, drives and thrusters etc. instead of building one from steel from scratch.
PS: You might want to put extra care on the protection of the air vents to the reactor core... or a well placed torpedo could end things ;)
Roche-Limit:
At first glance does not apply here. The marble is not being formed, it is being built. That is, there is so much internal stability, that the Roche-Limit does not apply to the stability of the marble.
The Roche-Limit tells you when a body is prone to start to lose its atmosphere, because of the influence of the other body's gravity. This could happen, but the effect would be cosmetic rather than severe.
As I understand it, the marble has no atmosphere (does not need one) and the planet also has none (because of that steel shell?). If it has, the biggest "problem" would be that the marble will pull some kind of tail of dust and particles from the atmosphere with it when starting the thrusters to leave again. But this "artificial atmosphere" will "fall off" as long as being inside the Roche-Limit of the planet and will not pose a problem to the functionality of the marble.
Conclusion:
Building such a marble is not the biggest problem. Navigating it and really be able to "roll" on a planet without severly destroying it by impact already is the bigger one. In any case, if the marble leaves the planet, that planet will never be the same again. Probably losing all habitability properties (due to changes in the rotational axis of a planet or breaking the stability of a Birch-Sphere).
